# Unable to get event for IOS app close in IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We are using IONIC for web, IOS, Android. We have a requirement of few logging when user closes browser or app. For this, "window:beforeunload" event is working perfectly fine or web, but could not able to get any close event for iOS app. Kindly, let me know if any event is available for ios app close, which we can use in ionic?

I tried using "window:beforeunload", which is working only in web. expecting app close event for IOS app.